# send message for validating input with pattern

Tags: angular

I have a component ValidationMessage that I use for displaying a validating message. ValidationMessage is used  in VendorComonent; also, I have a validationmessage_vendor ts file with the messages that will be displayed in a div

My problem is that it works fine for any validation like required or minlength, but doesn't work for the pattern that I am using

How to write this `type: 'pattern(\'^[0-9]{7}$\')'` in validationmessage_vm.ts file in order to work?

.ts method that involves the form

```
  initForm() {
    this.activateVendorForm = this.fb.group({
      vendorNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{7}$'), Validators.maxLength(7), Validators.minLength(7)]]
    })
  }
```

validationmessage_vm.ts

```
 const merchant_dashboard_vm = {
        'vendorNumber': [
            { type: 'required', message: 'Vendor Number is required'},
            { type: 'pattern(\'^[0-9]{7}$\')', message: 'Vendor Number should have 7 numbers'},
          ],
    };
    export default merchant_dashboard_vm;
```

validationmessage.component.ts

```
export class ValidationMessageComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() vm: string = '';
  @Input() control: any = null;
  @Input() controlName: string = '';

  validationMessages = null;

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.vm == 'merchant_dashboard_vm') this.validationMessages = merchant_dashboard_vm;
  }
}
```

validationmessage.component.html

```
<div class="from-group" *ngFor="let vm of validationMessages[controlName]">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="control.hasError(vm.type)">
          {{vm.message}}
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern inside the validators should be covered with the `forward` and `backward` slash instead of double-quotes.

```
Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]{7}$/)
```

Hope this helps!

```
 initForm() {
    this.activateVendorForm = this.fb.group({
      vendorNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]{7}$/), Validators.maxLength(7), Validators.minLength(7)]]
    })
  }
```

Comment: @user2004 what validation are you trying to do using that regex?

Comment: I have an input that must have type=text and it must contain only 7 numbers